# How to Navigate from a ListItem to its corresponding page?

Tags: listview, navigation, xamarin.forms

I have a ListView. What I am trying to achieve is that when I click on a list item, it should navigate to another page specific for that particular item.
I get an excpetion asking me to use a navigation page (please see the comment in code).

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1"
         x:Class="App1.MainPage"
         Title="MainPage">

 <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Dynamic ListView" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Label>
        <ListView x:Name="lstView" HasUnevenRows="true">

        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
 </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //BindingContext = this;

        string[] courses =
        {
            "ADO.NET  By Example",
            "Xamarin.Android",
            "Xamarin.iOS",
            "Xamarin.Forms",
            "JAVA EE: Java Server Pages",
            "JAVA EE: Programming Servlets"
        };

        lstView.ItemsSource = courses;

        lstView.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                // don't do anything if we just de-selected the row
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                if (e.SelectedItem.ToString() == "ADO.NET  By Example")
                {
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new Project1()); /// It throws an error here saying I need to use a Navigation Page.
                }
            }
        };   
    }
  }
```

The new page Project1 is at the same level as the MainPage. Also, I see that some people suggest changing the code in the GetMainPage() method. I don't have a GetMainPage() in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to use

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new Project1());
```

you must have defined your MaingPage as a NavigationPage

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

Then you can pass to Project1 your Item

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new Project1(e.SelectedItem));
```

I suggest to take a look to MVVM to have a cleanest code

Comment: I am not sure I understand this.

Comment: Your XF starting point is MainPage (you should change YOUR "MainPage" to use another name...). In App.cs you should set this MainPage to a NavigationPage like I have suggested in the post

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/ you can find a lot of sample to use Navigation in XF

Comment: Thanks. Putting this line MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage()); in my app.cs worked. Although now I need to know if this is the regular way of navigating from a list item? Or is this a workaround? How would I normally achieve this functionality.

Comment: It's the regular way to create a NavigationStack, so you can do Push and Pop